# Dispatch using socket io

Tags: react-native, redux, socket.io, react-redux, create-react-native-app

How can I change the state using socket?

> **socket.js**

```
import {getNearbyUser} from '../routes/Search/modules/Search'
export function socketAction(action,data){
    if(action == 'login'){
        socket.emit('login',data);
    }
    else if(action == 'book'){
        socket.emit('book',data);
    }

    socket.on('nearbyUser', getNearbyUser);
}
```

> **Search.js**

```
export function getNearbyUser(data){
    alert(data.latitude + '\n' + data.longitude);
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_NEARBY_HANDYMAN,
            address: data
        })
    }
}
```

> **server.js**

```
socket.on('handyman',(data) => {
    console.log(data);
    socket.to('customerRoom').emit('nearbyHandyman',data);
})
```

It alerts the latitude and longitude but the state is not changing or it's not dispatching.

Answer (score 0):

`getNearbyUser` returns a function which is never being called. Try:

```
socket.on('nearbyUser', data => getNearbyUser(data)(dispatch));
```

Not sure where `dispatch` is defined but you'll need to pass that in as well.

Comment: dispatch is defined in Search.js

Comment: Ok then there's no need to pass it as a param

Comment: You'll need to provide more details. Is the anonymous function that calls dispatch being invoked at all? If so, is dispatch defined?

Comment: My other function is just like that but the difference is they are not called in socket.